# Mocking Auth Token function in Pester

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester, pester-5

I have written a PowerShell function that generates an auth token in azure using REST API call. I am using the tenant id, Service principal client id and client secret as input param to generate this token. The SP client id and client secret are being read from the azure keyvault.

I wish to write a unit test to:

1. Read secret from keyvault
2. Mock the REST API call to generate dummy auth token

I am planning to use PESTER for unit testing and need some assistance here.

Here is my function:

```
function string GetAuthToken() {       
        $AuthTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"
        $Body = @{
            'resource'      = $resourcename
            'client_id'     = $ID
            'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials'
            'client_secret' = $Secret
        }
       $Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $AuthTokenUri -Body $Body -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       $AuthToken = ($Token.access_token).ToString()
       return $AuthToken
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want help setting up a mock REST API server? Or just a possible _response_ from one?

Comment: Thanks @Mathias R. Jessen for taking a look at this. I guess, I want to mock just the response. Basically, I want to be able to write a unit test for the actual functionality . i.e. generate an access token. (dummy) .

Comment: That should be as simple as calling `Mock Invoke-RestMethod { return "<sampleAzureKeyVaultJSONResponseGoesHere>" |ConvertFrom-Json }` :)

Comment: Which other function are you using to perform API calls? `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Right, so in that case you'll want to mock both `Invoke-RestMethod` and `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`. Same story though, `Mock <nameOfFunctionToMock> { return $objectThatLooksLikeAValidResponse }`

Comment: By calling `Mock` twice

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathias R. Jessen, that should do the job!